# Why FilterInputStream is not Abstract Class

Tags: java, abstract-class, inputstream, filter-input

we cannot instantiate java.io.FilterInputStream as it has no public constructor, we even don't need to without extending it.

why didn't they make that an abstract class?

Comment: We can't tell you why they designed it that way.  Anyone who does is only giving an opinion ... unless they were on the design team.  I expect that the real answer is that the API was designed in a hurry, and once the shortcomings were realized it was too late to fix them.

Comment: @StephenC And the design of that particular class was done around 1996, while Java was still a joke :)

Comment: To be frank, I personally even question the very reason for the existance of FilterInputStream. The class adds *nothing* of value IMO, since it doesn't add anything that allows interacting with the stream that isn't already part of the InputStream API.

Comment: (Going off on a tangent ... one of the nice things about the Ceylon language is that modules are versioned and you need to specify a version number in your imports.  This means that they can make incompatible changes to APIs without breaking old code.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically `protected` in Java includes both subclasses of the class in question, *and* other classes (not necessarily subclasses) that are in the same package.  So it would be possible for another class in `java.io` to directly instantiate a `FilterInputStream`.  The only reason I can think for why you'd want to do that is that `FilterInputStream.read(byte[] b)` delegates to `this.read(b, 0, b.length)` rather than `delegate.read(b)` so it's a way to prevent the delegate's `read(byte[])` method from ever getting called.  But that's all speculation on my part.

Other than that specific case, as you note it is *effectively* abstract, but it doesn't have any abstract methods so the compiler would not require that the class be declared abstract.

Comment: This still doesn't answer why it isn't abstract. If it's not to be instantiated at all, then it *should* be abstract for clarity.

Comment: my question is they could have done it in straight way, by just writing an "abstract", why they write 

protected FilterInputStream(InputStream in) {

 this.in = in;

    }

Comment: @rakeshmalik91 even if declared abstract it would still have needed a constructor taking the delegate stream.

Comment: @Ian Roberts i think this might be

Comment: @rakeshmalik91 The `protected` constructor is perfectly fine, but in addition to that, the class should really have been `abstract` to better declare its intent.

Answer (score 0):

> we cannot instantiate java.io.FilterInputStream as it has no public constructor

*We* cannot. Classes in the same package can.

Answer (score 0):

FilterInputStream does not have a public constructor (it is protected - You can see the javadoc), so you can't instantiate it directly. As i have studies that DataInputStream is derived from FilterInputStream (and DataInputStream does have a public constructor), so it can be instantiated.